# Reuse Trigger Conditions or MultiBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, controltemplate

#### Aim is to Reuse this MultiBinding in Various Places

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Value="True">
        <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValidationBooleanConverter}">
                    <Binding X" />
                    <Binding Y" />
                    <Binding Z" />        
                </MultiBinding>
        </Condition.Binding>
    </Condition>
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

#### Current not very [DRY](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/short-introduction-to-solid-and-dry-for.html) conditions (n+)

```
<Style x:Key="AnErrorTemplate" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
 <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
         <!-- Repeating the whole MultiTrigger.Conditions block here ---> 
         <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DirtyErrorControlTemplate}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

```
<Style x:Key="AnotherStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
 <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
         <!-- Repeating the whole MultiTrigger.Conditions block here ---> 
         <Setter Property="Other" Value="SomeValueIfTheSameConditionsAreTrue" />
    </MultiTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

*In fact, the requirements are broader, because I also need to re-use these same conditions in ControlTemplates.*

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="InlineErrorControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=InputView, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <MultiTrigger>
            <!-- Repeating the whole MultiTrigger.Conditions block here ---> 
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="SetMeIfTheseSameTriggerConditionsHold" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

#### An umbrella for easy maintenance?

Any ideas how I could specify the MultiTrigger.Conditions or the MultiBinding once only, and then use it in multiple styles and control templates?

- In XAML only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why `Style inheritance` was supplied in WPF. Plus in your case I will recommend to use `DataTrigger` with `MultiBinding` instead of `MultiTrigger` with `MultiBinding` ...

To demonstrate this lets assume I am creating a style that checks if the `Tooltip` or `Name` assigned to any `FrameworkElement` is empty. If so, it will make the `Foreground` red if the `FrameworkElement` is a `ComboBox` or its `Background` yellow if the `FrameworkElement` is `TextBox`.

I am using the miscellaneous field `Tag` of `FrameworkElement`....

So an all XAML (plus a C# converter) solution to this is as follows...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AtleastOneEmptyConverter x:Key="AtleastOneEmptyConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="BaseFrameworkElementStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                      <MultiBinding
                      Converter="{StaticResource AtleastOneEmptyConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ToolTip"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="Name"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="1"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ApplyToComboStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseFrameworkElementStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding Tag,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ApplyToTextBoxStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseFrameworkElementStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding Tag,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ApplyToComboStyle}"
                  x:Name="NotRedComboBox"
                  ToolTip="You will not see red text here">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">I am not Red!</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ApplyToComboStyle}">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">I am Red!</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Separator Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ApplyToTextBoxStyle}"
                 Text="I am yellow"
                 x:Name="YellowTextBox"/>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ApplyToTextBoxStyle}"
                 Text="I am not yellow"
                 x:Name="NotYellowTextBox"
                 ToolTip="You will not see yellow background here"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C# Converter:

```
public class AtleastOneEmptyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert
        (object[] values, Type targetType,
         object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Cast<string>().Any(val => string.IsNullOrEmpty(val));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack
        (object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Pointing out the use of the intermediate property was especially helpful (e.g. Tag)

Answer (score 2):

I've been in this situation many times where I want to reuse commonly used Bindings that set Converters, Validation Rules within those Converters, Notifying on Source/Target update, etc. by inheriting from Binding and reusing them by specifying:

```
Foreground="{b:CustomColorBinding CustomDateTime}"
```

to reduce the amount of XAML that I need to type for bindings, but don't believe there's a way to keep it all in XAML.  Trying to set the x:Key and use it as you would a Static or Dynamic Resource isn't possible, unfortunately.  I've become so accustomed to using this convention that I've created a BindingCatalog for my projects to store my common (multi) binding scenarios for different controls that bind to different types.

I'm sure you have good reasons to want to avoid code-behind but if you can create your MultiBinding in code once and reuse it to DRY up your XAML -- then I think it more than justifies the (overly-demonized, IMHO) code that will be required to do so.

Hope that helps in deciding what to do!

An extended binding

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class CustomBinding : Binding
    {
        public CustomBinding(String path)
            : base(path)
        {
            this.Converter = new CustomValueConverter();
            this.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            this.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Its XAML usage

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.UserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{local:CustomBinding MyViewModelProperty}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you and will try your approach if I get many different bindings to reuse, but I went with AngelWPF approach for now, mainly because he provided illustrative code :)

Comment: I take no offense at all, the approach AngelWPF mentioned above is a great one :)

Comment: I like to XAMLise the most that I can, but extending Binding class is very handy and a lot less verbose than XAML styling.

Comment: @sgissinger Please post a new answer instead of editing existing answers.

Comment: @Emil, and why ? If the system allow it ? And that's cool you removed what I did so I have to do it again... thanks